SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError is throwing error
I wrote an event receiver on GroupUserAdding. What I am doing is, I am replacing user being added with someone else. So, if user being added is user1 then it is replaced with user2
I am using SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError in code so it cancels actual event. All is working fine i.e. user is being successfully replaced while adding in group BUT it also throws exception at runtime Sorry something went wrong
Doesn't CancelNoError means cancel event but do not show/throw any error?

Using SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError is intended to cancel the event without indicating that an error occurred. However, if you are still encountering a runtime exception with the message "Sorry something went wrong," it suggests that there may be other issues in your event receiver code or the SharePoint environment that are not directly related to the cancellation status.
